# Grouping unit tests by class name in Visual Studio 2012 (Update 1)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to use the new features of Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 to group unit tests by class name?

I know this wasn't possible in the original release, but, it looks like some enhancements were made to the Test Explorer in Update 1.  I see there is now an option to group by project.  I also see that I can add custom traits to accomplish a similar grouping.

However, I was hoping there was an easy way to group by class name (without adding trait attributes to all of our tests). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Group by Class didn't make the Update 1. Stay tuned for CTP of Update 2.

Comment: Disappointed it didn't make it into the initial release and update 1, but good to see regular and more frequent updates.

Comment: I think I was able to group UnitTests in VS 2010, but I can't recall how I did this and I can't figure out how to do it in VS 2012 Ultimate. Is it supported now?

Comment: Ok, I was using the RTM version of VS 2012. Support for "TestCategory" was added with later updates. I'm updating my VS now.